# Search in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, rowfilter

I'm trying to make a search in my datagridview. 
I have this code for the textchange event.

```
Dt.Defaultview.RowFilter =string.Format("ID like '%" + SearchTextBox.Text +"%')
```

I also have a few summery rows in the datagridview (they make a sum of colum 4 for every few rows)

My target is to keep the summery rows when I'm using the search option (because now the summery rows are invisible when im using the search option.

I can recognize a summery row by cell 4; they have '*' as value.

Comment: First, looks like you are using `DataTable` as data source for your grid view. Are your "summary" rows included in that data table?

Comment: Yea im using this:  dt.InsertAt(dr,i);

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your "summary" rows in your data table, you can force them to be included in the filter by using `OR` condition like this:

```
string summaryFilter = ...;
Dt.Defaultview.RowFilter = summaryFilter + 
    " OR ID like '%" + SearchTextBox.Text +"%'";
```

The supported [DataView.RowFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) syntax is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Getting this error. Cannot preform '=' operation on System.String And System.int.    the summery coulm has a int value. And the ID coulm has a string value.

Comment: Apparently you have something wrong in `summaryFilter` condition. If you are using `int` column there, you cannot compare it to "*". When populating summary row, what do you put in that column? And how do you calculate it - in grid events?

Comment: Ok let me explain it better. I have column ID that have a numbers data. And i also stribg column: IdStatus that have a strings. And when the first number of the ID is changing (from 1 to 2 or 2 to 3) im doing a summery row on the IdStatus column. And all the others cells in this row are empty. Now i want to keep this sunmery row after im using the search option.

Comment: Read the answer again. Follow the provided links. All you need is to replace the `...` in the answer with **your** summary row criteria. For instance, "IdStatus = '*'" or something. You said you can recognize the summary rows, so just put that criteria using the syntax described in the link.

Comment: @ShmulikCohen Take a look at supported filter [expression format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) which provided in answer. For example when you want to compare string and integer, you can use `Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE '%something%'` in your filter expression.